# Playframework 2.3.x: Upload videos and large files using rest Web-Services with Scala

Tags: web-services, scala, rest, playframework-2.3

I am using Play-Framework and Scala for create a sample application. I am creating a `rest-full` web-services for client to access the applications. Now my major challenge is `How to upload videos using web-services in Play-Framework`. In the play documentation they only discuss about file upload. I never experienced before, for uploading videos using `rest-web-services`. Please guide me, from where i start?

Comment: Well, if it is a file, you can upload as any other discussed in the docs. Make sure to use multipart since it caches to disk. If you are planning to stream the video to the server, you need something else than a REST service.

Comment: Hello @AleksandarStojadinovic , my main task is to upload videos using webservices. How i map video parameter in webservice ?

Answer (score 1):

So... you want to upload video using Rest-full interface. hmmm.....  you seem to have not understood the concept of rest yet. I get the feeling that you currently think `JSON` as an integral part of Rest-full interfaces. And are actually trying to create a `Rest-full` interface which talks using `JSON`.

A Restful interface can be provided for uploading smaller files such as pictures etc ( by `byte64` encoding them ). Since videos can be considerably large, this method should not be used in this case.

But still, I can give you a pointer in one of the right directions.

One of the ways people do is in steps.

1. So... basically first you want your web service to know that you want to upload a video. This can be a rest-full endpoint, lets say `yourwebservice/upload`. Now the trick is to send all the meta-data about your upload to this endpoint, but don't send the actual video.
2. The actaul upload will be handled by another endpoint, lets say `yourwebservice/uploadActual` which can be non-restful ( I really mean non-JSON ) and should expect multipart-form data.
3. Now, on getting this request your `yourwebservice/upload` endpoint should do all preparations for upload ( creating folder etc ). Now, It will generate a UUID, save the fact that this UUID corresponds to the current upload-request and send back a response where it tells you that please upload to `yourwebservice/uploadActual/UUID`.
4. Now, just upload your file to `yourwebservice/uploadActual/UUID` as multipart-form data using any standard methods.
5. By looking at the UUID, your web service will know that this uploaded file corresponds to that upload request.

There are other ways to achieve this too, but I think this should provide you some help.